# Typescript Mapped Types or Arrays of Types

Tags: typescript

I am trying to use Typescript mapped types for a simple query API. Let me provide a simplified example:

```
interface IRoot {
  user: IUser,
  trips: Array<ITrip>
}

interface IUser {
  name: string
}

interface ITrip {
  prop: string
}
```

Now I can construct a query like this:

```
class Query<T, K extends keyof T> {
  constructor(
    private rootType: T, 
    private subQueries?: {[P in K]?: Query<T[P], any> }) { }
}
```

This works fine to access user, but can't resolve the type of the array for trips:

```
new Query(({} as IRoot), {
  user: new Query(({} as IUser), ... /* This is a query on User and is accepted here */, 
  trips: new Query(({} as ITrip), ... /* This is a query on Trip and TS will complain, since T[P] is Array<ITrip> */
})
```

Any ideas how I can extend `{[P in K]?: Query<T[P], any> }` to accept `T[P]` or if `T[P]` is an Array, the type of the array?

Comment: Is `trips: new Query(({} as Array<ITrip>), ...` not what you want?

Comment: No, this would make K the properties of array instead of ITrip. Instead, I want to access the props of the entity linked through a to-many relationship.

Comment: Don't think there is a way to do that, but maybe you can create an `interface IQuery<T>` and then you can have two classes `Query<T, K extends keyof T>` (`implements IQuery<T>`) and `ArrayQuery<T, K extends keyof T>` (implements `IQuery<T[]>`)

Comment: Could you define `trips` in `IRoot` as `trips: Array<ITrip> | ITrip`?

Comment: @Arg0n unfortunately not, since the Query result at some point also uses T[P] and the query returns an array of queried references.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir In this case subqueries would need to have the type: `{[P in K]?: Query<T[P], any> | ArrayQuery<T[P], any> }`, however, Typescript complains that `T[P]` does not satisfy the type constraint `any[]` for the ArrayQuery

Comment: @jpkraemer The type would be `{[P in K]?: IQuery<T[P]> }`. And since `ArrayQuery<T>` actually `implements IQuery<T[]>` the types should match. I can provide the whole code as an answer if you think it may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea would be to create an `IQuery` interface and create two implementations, one for simple properties and one for array properties. `Query` will implement IQuery and ArrayQuery will implement IQuery. The `IQuery` interface will need to have a have a method or field that uses T in order to ensure `ArrayQuery<T>` and `Query<T>` are structurally incompatible.

```
interface IQuery<T> {
    // We need this method since the compiler checks structural compatibility we need to make implementations of IQuery<T> and IQuery<T[]> incompatible.
    getRootType(): T;
}
class Query<T, K extends keyof T> implements IQuery<T>{
    constructor(
      private rootType: T, 
      private subQueries?: {[P in K]?: IQuery<T[P]> }) { 

      }
    getRootType(): T {
          return this.rootType;
    }
}

class ArrayQuery<T, K extends keyof T> implements IQuery<T[]>{
    constructor(private rootType: T,private  subQueries?: {[P in K]?: Query<T[P], any> }) { 

    }
    getRootType(): T[]{
        return [this.rootType];
    }
}

new Query(({} as IRoot), {
    user: new Query(({} as IUser)), 
    trips: new ArrayQuery(({} as ITrip)) 
});
```